# How to query for posts with a null or blank post_name?

Tags: php, wp-query

I am trying to query for all posts that have an empty post_name.  I have 2 posts in my DB that meet the requirements below.

`$posts = new wp_query("Select id, post_title from wp_posts where post_name = '' AND post_status='publish');`

When I run the above in inside my site code, WP returns 44 posts that are all blank IDs and not the 2 I set up for testing.  When I run the exact query on the DB I get my 2 results.

What am I doing wrong in WP?

Comment: As far as I know WP_Query takes an array of arguments, and not a string. You should look into the [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class for custom queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WP_Query:

```
$no_title_posts = new WP_Query(array('name'=>'','posts_per_page'=>-1);
```

That will search all posts with empty name. The posts_per_page = "-1" returns all posts because by default wp returns 10 or whatever number you have selected in your admin settings.

if you want to retrieve it from other posts types (default is "post"), then you will need to specify it:

```
$no_title_pages = new WP_Query(array('name'=>'','posts_per_page'=>-1,'post_type'=>'page);
```

Comment: Same results, 44 results that don't return ID's and all the fields are blank.  I did not use args in my example just so I could do an exact comparison.  I am not too worried about how pretty it looks either, since this is a 1 time script.

Comment: Weird.... I removed some titles from my database and ran the query... it only found the ones without titles.